# History object in Firefox private mode

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a simple page with a back to safety button with pure JavaScript; Vanilla.

The button has a `onclick` event which checks the history object, and see if the length of it is more than one, the URL change to the old URL, otherwise, a blank page will be opened.

```
var goBack = function () {
    if (window.history.length > 1) {
        window.history.back();
    } else { 
        //window.location = "about:blank";
        window.location.assign("about:blank");
    }
};
```

It works fine on Chrome normal, incognito mode, and fine in normal Firefox, but when I try to use it in Private Mode of Firefox, the page gets refreshed every time that, I click on back to safety. Apparently, the history of browsing during the session if available for the user since the user can click on forward and backward of navigation bar in Firefox private mode

What can I do to make back to safety button work properly in FF private mode?

Comment: What can you do for what?

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) are you making ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) [[tag:firefox-webextensions]],  [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-sdk]], [Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) [[tag:firefox-addon-restartless]], or [Overlay/XUL/Legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-overlay]]/[[tag:xul]])? Please [edit] the appropriate tag into your question.

Comment: @Makyen: I edited the question. for final question, and tags

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].